# QGIS installation instructions fail

Tags: qgis, installation

This is the "instructions box" at https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html (example of *debian-ubuntu* instruction for ),

[image]

The last red line is the problem, with no explicit instruction and it seems where my `apt` install fails, because it resulted in an **old** "3.22.4-Białowieża" version, instead of a new version **new** 3.32 version.

### How to add the red line?

The instructions say nothing, only describes that the last `wget` command  "Add the QGIS repo for the latest stable QGIS (3.32.x Lima) to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/qgis.sources"... But it is false, there is **no `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/qgis.sources`** (error *"No such file or directory"*).

With no extra procedure for the red line it also runs

1. `sudo apt update` (Ok)
2. `sudo apt install qgis qgis-plugin-grass` (Ok but install **bad version!!**)

I need a **new** version.

### Fail in the first clues

First clues posted by @bugmenot123 also fail (!).

1. I created the "red line file" by `sudo cat >  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/qgis.sources`
2. I do copy/paste of the supposed content [image]
3. I do again `apt update` (after `apt purge qgis`) and it fails:

```
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [274 kB]
Err:11 https://debian.qgis.org/debian your-distributions-codename Release                    
  404  Not Found [IP: 2606:4700:3035::6815:4729 443]
...
E: The repository 'https://qgis.org/debian your-distributions-codename Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

---

PS1: please at answer say also how to **purge** the old installed v3.22.4.

PS2: `lsb_release -cs` for my Linux results in "jammy" (and it exists at QGIS as https://debian.qgis.org/debian/dists/jammy/)

Comment: @user2856 I added it, see PS2.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/qgis.sources` file yet, you can simply create it.

Either use an editor like nano, mousepad, geany etc to edit the file directly:

`sudo YOUREDITOR /etc/apt/sources.list.d/qgis.sources`

or create a `qgis.sources` text file with your normal user using any text editor and then move it using `sudo mv qgis.sources /etc/apt/sources.list.d/`

Purging a package using apt is done by `apt purge packagename`, so e.g. `apt purge qgis`.

### `qgis.sources` file is a template

You need to fill the `Suites` value:

```
Types: deb deb-src
URIs: https://qgis.org/debian
Suites: $your_distributions_codename
Architectures: amd64
Components: main
Signed-By: /etc/apt/keyrings/qgis-archive-keyring.gpg
```

So, replace the placeholder `$your_distributions_codename` by "jammy" (that was in your case the result of `lsb_release -cs`).

```
Suites: jammy
```

Comment: Thanks @bugmenot123! I need to fill the qgis.sources file with a content, where the content for copy/paste? – not make sense a `wget` for one file and a copy/paste for other... Why not both?

Comment: The text to copy is in the box below the words "Add the QGIS repo for the latest stable QGIS (3.32.x Lima) to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/qgis.sources:"

Comment: Thanks @user2856, was only for confirmation because, as I edited the question, the copy/paste content is not working fine. See "404  Not Found [IP]" and "does not have a Release file" errors. Now I edited the answer with the template explanation... and perfect, installed v3.32!

Comment: Conclusion. It's 2023 but, there is decidedly **no plug-and-play installer for QGIS**.

Comment: You can just use the QGIS provided by your distro. You can use a multitude of options for other installers. You can follow installation instructions step by step and install QGIS that way. Etc etc. Don't complain.

Answer (score 0):

I did

```
sudo wget -O /etc/apt/keyrings/qgis-archive-keyring.gpg https://download.qgis.org/downloads/qgis-archive-keyring.gpg

sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/qgis.list

# in nano
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/qgis-archive-keyring.gpg] https://qgis.org/debian <codename> main
deb-src [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/qgis-archive-keyring.gpg] https://qgis.org/debian <codename> main
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).